# Is Thanos the *only* survivor of the collapse of Titan?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Is Thanos from *Avengers: Infinity War* the *only* survivor of the collapse of Titan? Where are his fellow Titans?

Do the comics shed some light on this or is it just considered not important?

Comment: You should ask this on SciFi.SE as it is more related to the comics than the movie.

Comment: Comics are completely different - they do have a lot more details, but Thanos is pretty much completely different guy there along with his origin, with mostly superficial resemblance.

Comment: I'm asking somewhat more for the Marvel Cinematic Universe, hence being asked here.  Since the comics rely on, but sometimes diverge from the comics, its a relevant question here and on SciFi for the comics.  In addition, I hear there's deleted scenes on the Blu-Ray Infinity War, so anybody who has that might be able to shed light on the subject.

Answer (score -4):

He's not the last Titan he's the Mad Titan he was formed he was born disfigured this is Channon face and stuff and then cast or exiled from Titan by the other Titans so I know he's not the only Titan left he's just exiled for deformity

Comment: His second goal other than getting death to fall in love with him by collecting The Gauntlet and it's Stones was to defeat the Titans that exiled him but Lady Death may never show up in the MCU because that was much later but there are supposed to be 21 more movies made hopefully I'll be alive to see them LOL

Comment: What do you base all this information on?

Comment: Secret Wars 1 & 2 1985 and mini clips from the films, Guardians of the Galaxy animated series. Also could you tell me how to add that spoiler box. I'm new here but think I added a spoiler.

Comment: When I spoke of Tantos being in love with Mistress Death. I wasn't talking about Hela the queen of death there two different characters in the MCU comic series I don't know if they'll be added to the movie collection Cinema but that's Thanos's goal is her love (Mistress Death not Hela)

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! You add spoiler tags like this - `>!` - though I don't think you'd need them in this instance.